# csrf_token problem django

Tags: python, django, forms, csrf

I have put in the {% csrf_token %} and the `context_instance=RequestContext(request))` but I still get the error `CSRF token missing or incorrect`. Thanks in advance! or not.

Comment: you should carefully read the docs about [how to use csrf token](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it). If it's failing, paste your code

Comment: For example you didn't mention setting up the CsrfViewMiddleware ... but wihout further details it's hard to help you.

Comment: Can you even see the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` hidden field when you inspect the form html?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the CSRF token template variable is *inside* your form. If you're sure it is, view the page's HTML source to make sure that it's actually printing out the hidden input field. If all else fails, check your settings to make sure the CSRF middleware is enabled and configured properly.

Additionally, having the source (or at least a few lines of context) would be greatly helpful in figuring out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You append {% csrf_token %} to the form ? (<form>{% csrf_token %} ...</form>)

Answer (score 0):

Use the {% csrf_token %}  validation inside your HTML form as sample below.

`<form> {% csrf_token %} </form>`